# Trigger animation on page load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-animations

I have a code  that triggers an animation on some elements when they're hovered by adding a second css class on them, and once it's done, this class is removed so it becomes static again. I don't know how to make the animation happen every time the page is loaded tho, I tried adding a "window.load" function but it didn't work out. I'd appreciate if someone could shed me a light on it.

Here's the snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/6fmno8vb/1/

```js
$(".draw, .draw2, .logo-box").on("animationend webkitAnimationEnd", function () {
    $(this).addClass("done");
    if (!$(".draw:not(.done), .draw2:not(.done), .logo-box:not(.done)").length) {
        $(".draw.done, .draw2.done, .logo-box").removeClass("anim").removeClass("done");
    }
});

$(".main-logo").mouseenter(function () {
    $(".draw, .draw2, .logo-box").addClass("anim");
});
```

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}

.main-logo {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 30%;
    display: block;
}

.logo-box {
    background: #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.logo-box.anim {
    transform: scale(1.07) translate(-3px, 3px);
    transition: all 0.15s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
}

.draw {
    background: #d7cf00;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.draw.anim {
    animation: animate 1.5s ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.draw2 {
    background: #db0a28;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.draw2.anim {
    animation: animate 1.5s ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animate {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }
    20% {
        transform: scale(0.3);
    }
    60% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div class="main-logo">
        <div class="logo-box">
            <div class="draw"></div>
            <div class="draw2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add at least the animation, at best a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Am I the only one thinking this is a pure CSS task with `:hover`?

Comment: Sorry, I've added the example in practice. I don't think it's possible to make that work just with :hover because I want the animation not to be interrupted on mouse leave, or even restarted by a new hover before all the keyframes are completed. But if you can make it work with pure css that'd be really awesome! Please let me know if there's a better way to execute this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I will give two solutions.**

Wrap event `mouseenter` with a window `load` event.

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    ...
    $(".main-logo").trigger("mouseenter");
});
```

```js
$(window).on("load", function () {
    $(".draw, .draw2, .logo-box").on("animationend webkitAnimationEnd", function () {
        $(this).addClass("done");
        if (!$(".draw:not(.done), .draw2:not(.done), .logo-box:not(.done)").length) {
            $(".draw.done, .draw2.done, .logo-box").removeClass("anim").removeClass("done");
        }
    });

    $(".main-logo").mouseenter(function () {
        $(".draw, .draw2, .logo-box").addClass("anim");
    });

    $(".main-logo").trigger("mouseenter");
});
```

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}

.main-logo {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 30%;
    display: block;
}

.logo-box {
    background: #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.logo-box.anim {
    transform: scale(1.07) translate(-3px, 3px);
    transition: all 0.15s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
}

.draw {
    background: #d7cf00;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.draw.anim {
    animation: animate 1.5s ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.draw2 {
    background: #db0a28;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.draw2.anim {
    animation: animate 1.5s ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animate {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }
    20% {
        transform: scale(0.3);
    }
    60% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div class="main-logo">
        <div class="logo-box">
            <div class="draw"></div>
            <div class="draw2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

If you trigger a mouse event immediately after the page is launched, then it does not always look efficient. I advise you to wrap the event `mouseenter` call in `setTimeout()`, specifying any *appropriate* value for the delay.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(".main-logo").trigger("mouseenter");
}, 1000);
```

```js
setTimeout(function () {
    $(".main-logo").trigger("mouseenter");
}, 1000);

$(".draw, .draw2, .logo-box").on("animationend webkitAnimationEnd", function () {
    $(this).addClass("done");
    if (!$(".draw:not(.done), .draw2:not(.done), .logo-box:not(.done)").length) {
        $(".draw.done, .draw2.done, .logo-box").removeClass("anim").removeClass("done");
    }
});

$(".main-logo").mouseenter(function () {
    $(".draw, .draw2, .logo-box").addClass("anim");
});
```

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}

.main-logo {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 30%;
    display: block;
}

.logo-box {
    background: #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.logo-box.anim {
    transform: scale(1.07) translate(-3px, 3px);
    transition: all 0.15s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
}

.draw {
    background: #d7cf00;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.draw.anim {
    animation: animate 1.5s ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.draw2 {
    background: #db0a28;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.draw2.anim {
    animation: animate 1.5s ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animate {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }
    20% {
        transform: scale(0.3);
    }
    60% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div class="main-logo">
        <div class="logo-box">
            <div class="draw"></div>
            <div class="draw2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for taking your time! In the first snippet it works exactly how I imagined it, but when I try to apply the script on my page, the animation on page load is not triggered. Any idea of what could be happening? I literally just replaced the previous script I had by yours.

Comment: @matheusrvdc, I suppose this is some kind of small problem. Perhaps you just don't have time to see this animation. Are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: I didn't come across any error in the  console. I've done several tests and your code works perfectly well when I reproduce it isolated, even with all the original code and animations (here I just put a random animation with squares for the sake of simplicity). But when I incorporate it into the header file of my site, the animation on page load is not triggered, it only happens on mouse over. Any suggestion on what could possibly be preventing it from being triggered? Thanks a lot for the attention

Answer (score 1):

Dear according to your question you want the animation to be loaded on page load, so I have added document. ready function and also your old function is also there, so both functionalities on hover and on page is load is available

```js
$(".draw, .draw2, .logo-box").on("animationend webkitAnimationEnd", function () {
    $(this).addClass("done");
    if (!$(".draw:not(.done), .draw2:not(.done), .logo-box:not(.done)").length) {
        $(".draw.done, .draw2.done, .logo-box").removeClass("anim").removeClass("done");
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".draw, .draw2, .logo-box").addClass("anim");
});

$(".main-logo").mouseenter(function () {
    $(".draw, .draw2, .logo-box").addClass("anim");
});
```

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}

.main-logo {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 30%;
    display: block;
}

.logo-box {
    background: #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.logo-box.anim {
    transform: scale(1.07) translate(-3px, 3px);
    transition: all 0.15s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
}

.draw {
    background: #d7cf00;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.draw.anim {
    animation: animate 1.5s ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.draw2 {
    background: #db0a28;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.draw2.anim {
    animation: animate 1.5s ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animate {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }
    20% {
        transform: scale(0.3);
    }
    60% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="main-logo">
        <div class="logo-box">
            <div class="draw"></div>
            <div class="draw2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```